# Nivo Slider rendering problems in multiple browsers

Tags: css, nivo-slider

[image: IE9 screenshot]
[image]

Hey, y'all!  I am building a site using the Nivo Slider (which I've normally had great success with).  But I'm having some issues with this particular usage that I just can't figure out.  Any help from you code wizards would be greatly appreciated!

Test site is [here.](http://www.603mediagroup.com/uvcleaning/site/index.html)

In Firefox, as usual, the site looks fantastic.  Everything works, nothing broken.
In Opera, pretty much the same.

<strike>In IE9, however, the slider looks great until it transitions to the next image.  The slider uses a float:right property and, in Explorer, each transition causes the image to momentarily jump all the way to the left of the container div.</strike> **THIS PROBLEM SOLVED.**  The "float:right" property was only placed on the slider images and not to the slider container, itself.  The corrected code now causes both the individual images AND the overall slider container to float to the right.

In Safari, the slider looks great unless you resize the page to anything less than 100% - then, the images do not shrink with the surrounding content.

<strike>In Chrome, surprisingly, the thing is all messed up.  On first load, the slider doesn't appear.  If I reduce the viewing size to 90%, it appears fine including when I size back up to 100%.  However, the caption function is not popping out as far as it does on the other browsers (see the site to understand what I mean).</strike> **THIS PROBLEM SOLVED** It turns out that the bullets that control the slides were the problem.  Or, more accurately, the div surrounding them was.  The div for the .controlNav bullets had a "position:absolute" property that worked fine in all the other browsers but that screwed up Chrome for whatever reason.  I eliminated those bullets entirely as they're really not necessary for this particular site.  Problem solved.  **Unfortunately, the methods used have buggered up Safari rendering of the slider completely, so now I have to figure that out.**

I have done quite a bit of searching on this topic and have found many problems with the Nivo Slider, particularly in IE, but nothing that exactly relates to what I am experiencing.  I suspect that some of the issue is being caused by the float:right property that the Slider typically doesn't get used with (most sites use it in a centered-on-page capacity), but I don't know this for absolute certain.

Here is the slider HTML (there is a metric buttload of CSS for the Nivo Slider so I won't paste it here.  You can look at the stylesheets using your browser's developer tools.) :

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="layout-wrapper">
        <aside id="slider" class="theme-default">
            <div id="nivo-slider" class="nivoSlider slider-underline">
                <img src="images/slider-img1.jpg" class="attachment-slider_nivo" title="#slide-1" />
                <img src="images/slider-img2.jpg" class="attachment-slider_nivo" title="#slide-2" />
                <img src="images/slider-img3.jpg" class="attachment-slider_nivo" title="#slide-3" />
            </div>
            <!-- end #nivo-slider -->
            <div id="slide-1" class="nivo-html-caption" data-position="right">
                <span class="slider_title">Tile and Ceramic Cleaning</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit. Suspendisse enim arcu, convallis non, cursus sed, dignissim et, est. Aenean semper aliquet libero.</p>
                <a href="#" title="" class="more align-right">Read more »</a>
            </div>
            <!-- end #slide-1 -->
            <div id="slide-2" class="nivo-html-caption" data-position="left">
                <span class="slider_title">Kitchen Cleaning and Sanitizing</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit. Suspendisse enim arcu, convallis non, cursus sed, dignissim et, est. Aenean semper aliquet libero.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end #slide-2 -->
            <div id="slide-3" class="nivo-html-caption" data-position="right">
                <span class="slider_title">Full Residential Services!</span>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nunc suscipit. Suspendisse enim arcu, convallis non, cursus sed, dignissim et, est. Aenean semper aliquet libero.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end #slide-3 -->
        </aside>
        <div class="banner-1"></div>
        <!-- end #slider -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .layout-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- end #header -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I appreciate any and all tips you folks can come up with!

Comment: Does the HTML of the site properly pass validation?

Comment: No, it does not:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.603mediagroup.com%2Fuvcleaning%2Fsite%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @Sparky I only see one error there that might *actually* mess with the rendering of the site.

Comment: @ryan, with all of his mysterious cross-brower rendering problems, it _might_ be a good idea for the OP to rule it out.

Comment: @Sparky The only validation errors I get in Dreamweaver are for HTML5 coding styles.  I haven't upgraded Dreamweaver in a long time so it doesn't recognize a lot of the newer coding.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Dreamweaver to write code, let alone validate it.  You have a stray semicolon `;` within a couple of your elements, a few duplicate `id`'s, and some other minor things.  See:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.603mediagroup.com%2Fuvcleaning%2Fsite%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Placing the alt="" back into the HTML did not fix the problem.  Ignoring the other errors on the validator for the moment since they are simple text issues and would not relate to the slider issue.  Should also mention that this site was a template that's been heavily modified and was guaranteed to be HTML5-compliant.  All the errors in the basic structure coding are kinda' annoying....

Comment: Duplicate `id`'s and a stray character inside several elements are not minor.  See `<p style="font-style:italic";>`  Notice the `;`?  No guarantee this fixes anything, but I never have cross-browser issues when my page passes HTML validation.

Comment: @Sparky - For the sake of argument, I fixed the errors.  The only three I left alone are for the form because I need to study up on forms a bit before I go screwing with code written by someone else.  Regardless, none of those errors, as predicted, relate at all to the Chrome or Safari rendering issues.  Wondering if there are any other ideas with the info given?  Thanks for all the help, so far!

Comment: It's good to rule them out at least.

Comment: My only advice would be to start with a blank HTML page and install nothing but your Nivo code.  If it works, then install another section or component.  Test and repeat.  Eventually, you'll find the one piece that's breaking this.  It's painful, but otherwise, you could be trying out various random theories for days.

Comment: @Ryan and Sparky- Getting this figured out, piece by piece.  Please see my edits to my original post, above.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `<aside>` tag with a `<div>` tag. I did that in the chrome inspector tools, and it seemed to work fine after that.

I am using the `nivo-slider` on 4-5 different websites right now, never seen it use the `<aside>` tag.

Comment: No dice.  This is also the first nivo code I've downloaded that uses the <aside> rather than a <div>.  But still no change.  I've attached a screenshot of the Chrome problem.  Images disappear, nav buttons remain although they are placed differently on the page.  Doesn't matter what viewing size I start at, either.  If I start at, say, 90%, slider doesn't show until I upsize or downsize.

Comment: @user1902087 what version of chrome are you using? because on the latest version I am not seeing the issues you are seeing. even when I re-size the window

Comment: It's the latest, according to Google.  Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: @user1902087 have you cleared your cache since you updated the code? when I open your link now (since you replaced `aside` tag, it seems to be working perfectly